# Remove symbol after n'th occurrence in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

I want to remove semicolons after the 7th occurrence, on multiple rows that may look like this:

foo;10.10.10.10;/24;;NA;;;foo; bar; "foobar"

Meaning that the result should be like this:

foo;10.10.10.10;/24;;NA;;;foo bar "foobar"

What I have been able to do so far is to segment the parts into capture groups:

:%s/(.{-};.{-};.{-};.{-};.{-};.{-};.{-};)(.*)

My problem is that I don't know how to delete characters within a capture group - how do I go about this?

Comment: Have a look there: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27178/vim-s-replace-first-n-g-occurrences-on-a-line You want M = 8 and N big enough.

Comment: Thank you, using that method I used this string:

:call feedkeys(repeat("n", 7-1) . repeat("y", 100-7+1)) | s/;//gc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
:%s/\v^([^;]*;){7}\zs.*/\=substitute(submatch(0), ';', '', 'g')/
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it works like intended. Didn't know about the substitute function so learned something new today!

Answer (score 1):

if every line has the same format you could simply use macros.
Macros also give you an elastic way to the more processing in clearly and intuitive way - you just do what you want in the simplest way you know and vim repeated it.
In this example it would be:

**lines**

```
foo;10.10.10.10;/24;;NA;;;foo; bar; "foobar"
foo;10.10.10.10;/24;;NA;;;foo; bar; "foobar"
foo;10.10.10.10;/24;;NA;;;foo; bar; "foobar"
```

**record macro**

```
qa08f;xjq
```

**and repeat N-times, eg 1000**

```
1000@a
```

**explanation:**

```
qa - record macro with name a
0 - move cursor to the begging of line
8f; - move cursor to the 8th occurences of semicolon
x - remove semicolon
j - move cursor to the next line
q - finish macro

And repeat macro number of times you need
1000@a
```

Comment: Haven't used macros before so this was a great how-to. However this one only removes the 8th occurrence of semicolon, the rest remains.

Comment: I didn't catch that.
But if you want to remove 8th and the rest occurences of ; then you could evolve macro. This will work if the amount of occurencies is the same in earch line. In this one you have 9th occurencies, so it would be:
`qa08f;x;xjq`

Explanation:
`qa08f;x` - the same. Then `;x` this mean move cursor to the next occurrence and remove the one. Please don't be confused with semicolon in this context. `;` here means to go to next occurrence of the character previously found by `f` command
`jq` and this means the same as previously of course

Answer (score 0):

You also can use this regex:

```
:%s/\(\(.\{-};\)\{7}\)\|;/\1/g
```